# After taking turtle to other turtle's y coordinate, the program crashes. Any fixes?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Here's the full code

```
import os

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Score
score_a = 0
score_b = 0

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("square")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 0.5
ball.dy = 0.5

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Player 1: 0  Player 2: 0", align="center", font=("Impact", 24, "normal"))


# Functions
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)


# Keyboard bindings
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

     # Computer player
    if ball.xcor() > 250:
        paddle_b.goto (ball.ycor())

    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Border checking

    # Top and bottom
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1
        os.system("afplay bounce.wav&")

    elif ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1
        os.system("afplay bounce.wav&")

    # Left and right
    if ball.xcor() > 350:
        score_a += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player 1: {}  Player 2: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Impact", 24, "normal"))
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    elif ball.xcor() < -350:
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player 1: {}  Player 2: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Impact", 24, "normal"))
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    # Paddle and ball collisions
    if ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() - 50:
        ball.dx *= -1 
        os.system("afplay bounce.wav&")

    elif ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() - 50:
        ball.dx *= -1
        os.system("afplay bounce.wav&")
```

I'm trying to make a computer player with `# Computer player
    if ball.xcor() > 250:
        paddle_b.goto (ball.ycor())`

Each time the ball's xcor gets passed 250, the program crashes. Any fixes?

It wont let me post till I have more text ignore this please
It wont let me post till I have more text ignore this please
It wont let me post till I have more text ignore this please

I always feel like

Somebodys watching meee

And I got no privacy

Oh Oh Oh

Comment: where is `turtle` defined? also you should include details about the error output when the program crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your main problem is that `paddle_b.goto` uses an x/y point, not just the y-coordinate which you're inputting from the ball.

This should be giving you the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<Path>", line 85, in <module>
    paddle_b.goto(ball.ycor())
  File "<Path>\turtle.py", line 1774, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(*x))
TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not float
```

From the documentation of goto ( https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.goto ):

> If y is None, x must be a pair of coordinates or a Vec2D (e.g. as returned by pos()).

You should be able to do: `paddle_b.sety(ball.ycor())` instead, which only needs the y-coordinate and you use already. Alternatively, another way to solve this is to keep the X-coordinate of the paddle the same through: `paddle_b.goto(paddle_b.xcor(), ball.ycor())`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way to make this less accurate and more of a smooth transition? Thank you.

Comment: You could implement acceleration using the distance of the ball from the paddle and how far off the paddle is from intercepting the ball calculated during each frame and applied as an offset to the current paddle position, though I’ll leave that as an exercise for you to implement as that’s the fun part and will help learning. If you know about the connection between acceleration, velocity, and position, then it should not be too difficult. Momentum could also be taken into account to further smooth the paddle’s movements.